# Dukt Social Plugin Not Creating User

Tags: users, registration, plugin-duktoauth, plugin-social-login

I'm currently Authenticating users via OAuth and Social Login by Dukt. I have Facebook app all set up and running as well as Twitter. The user gets redirected, asked to Authorise but when it returns back to the Craft website the user hasn't been created or exists.

My current setup is as follows:

- Connected Facebook to OAuth
- Connected Facebook with Social Login
- Activated my Facebook app so it's "Live"

My questions are as follows:

- I haven't got a config file for the user, do we need to create this?
- Do you need to add "Fields" to the "User" in Craft CP such as Username/Email? If so - which ones are the defaults for social login?

Thanks